# GridLines make figure exported to EPS locally bitmap (?!)

Tags: graphics, export, eps-format, grid-lines

Noticed strange behaviour of `Export[]` when saving graphics to EPS. Here is an example figure I am exporting:

```
fig =
 Show[
  ListPolarPlot[
   Table[{a, .9}, {a, 0, 2 Pi, .001}], 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 1.1}, {0, 1.1}}, GridLines -> Automatic, 
   PlotStyle -> PointSize[.005]],

  Graphics[
   Inset[
    ListPolarPlot[Table[{a, .1}, {a, 0, 2 Pi, .001}], Axes -> False, 
     PlotStyle -> PointSize[.05]],
    {.4, .4}]
   ]
  ]
```

The exported figure does not look fine upon a close look --- horizontal grid lines seem to be rasterised:
[image: zoom into the figure 1]

If I now apply `GridLinesStyle -> Thick`, the problem disappears:
[image: zoom into the figure 2]

Any ideas why that happens? I use Mathematica for MacOS v. 11.0.1.0.

Can anyone with MMA v11 reproduce the issue?

Comment: Not sure if this is relevant here, but anything that invokes `Opacity` will cause an `eps` to be rasterized. ( I do not know if the automatic grid style might use opacity )

Comment: Having said that I just ran it and can not reproduce the issue.  Can you open the two eps files in a text editor and compare. Even if you aren't familiar with postscript it will be obvious if you have big blocks of ascii-encoded binary raster.  The file size is a clue too ( I get the same 372kb with or without  `GridLinesStyle -> Thick` )

Comment: @george2079 files are very close in size, though much heavier than what you get (3.4 mb). I cannot see any blocks of ascii in these files, here are the files in case you want to have a look ([auto](https://www.dropbox.com/s/p5g8u81mqqrulwa/GL_automatic.eps?dl=0), [thick](https://www.dropbox.com/s/djkuy22m1vtyw5e/GL_thick.eps?dl=0)). I cannot find a way check the default style for gridlines (if it has any opacity).

Comment: your files are vastly different from mine (v10.1,windows). As near as i can tell they are rendering the lines not as postscript lines but a as filled polygons (thousands of little rectangles), and there is a small binary raster (search for "image" in the eps files) that is possibly the polygon fill pattern.  Sorry I have no idea how to fix.   Can you see if you have the same issue with plain `ListPlot`?  I'd also try without using  `Inset` to see if that is the issue.

Comment: @george2079 I do not use `Joined` option, hence the polygons might actually be plot points. The issue persists in both cases (plain `ListPlot`, no `Inset`). Interestingly, vertical grid lines are rendered correctly. Maybe that's v11 bug?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default grid lines style uses uses partially transparent grid lines:

```
InputForm@AbsoluteOptions[fig, GridLinesStyle]
(* {GridLinesStyle -> Directive[GrayLevel[0.5, 0.4]]} *)
```

where the second argument of `GrayLevel` specifies opacity. As pointed out by george2079 in the comments, this causes the exported eps file to be partially rasterized.

Specifying `GridLinesStyle -> Thick` removes the default specification, fixing the problem, but changing the appearance. You can keep the original appearance with `GridLinesStyle -> GrayLevel[.8]`:

```
fig = Show[ListPolarPlot[Table[{a, .9}, {a, 0, 2 Pi, .001}], 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 1.1}, {0, 1.1}}, GridLinesStyle -> GrayLevel[.8],
  GridLines -> Automatic, PlotStyle -> PointSize[.005]], 
  Graphics[Inset[ListPolarPlot[Table[{a, .1}, {a, 0, 2 Pi, .001}], Axes -> False, 
  PlotStyle -> PointSize[.05]], {.4, .4}]]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First do correct exporting procedure

```
Export["/Users/jecalderon1/Documents/testFigreu.eps", fig, "EPS"]
```

Off course, you have to change the direction of the directory path../user/ to your local directory.

Then open using Adobe Illustrator . Will render the correct way.

Comment: I use the same export procedure. An application I use to view the file does not seem to be important.